# Can I get document.URL without dot?

Tags: javascript, html, alert, document

I know, that I can get alert with URL by code

`with(document)alert(URL)`

So, I need to take this value to the variable x. Can I did it?

I don't know how to do it. What I should write instead alert? I need it without dot.

`var x=(with(document)____(URL))`

Comment: `document["URL"]`? Not sure what you have against dots...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey thank you! :)

Comment: `with(document)var x=URL`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)